# wso2 api manager 1.6.0 problems with User store management using ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager

Tags: active-directory, ldap, wso2

I'm trying to setup a ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager as a secondary user store. But I cannot seem to get the Role assignment of users correct.

What I have done so far:
- Made the AD ldap-connection
- Retrieved the users from the AD
- Retrieved the roles from the AD
- Can view Users that are connected to a specific role in API Manager Gui

My problem:
When I go to a user and click "View Roles" in the API Manager Gui ({IP}:9443/carbon/user/user-mgt.jsp) I get a "No matching roles found" dialog. But when I go to a Role ({IP}:9443/carbon/role/role-mgt.jsp) and click "View Users" I can see that the user I "View Roles" of above is actually in that role.

So obviously I have some sort of miss connection between the Users that are connected to Roles and the Roles that are connected to a User. I just cannot figure out where I'm getting it wrong.

If anyone would give me any hint or even ask a question about something I haven't already tried that would be awesome!

[image: API manager and xml-config file]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with your RoleDNPattern. You can first try by commenting it and see if it resolves the problem. If it does, then have to compose the correct query for that.

Comment: Hi Amila De Silva, thanks for you answer! I have tried without the RoleDNPattern and when I found that property I really though I would solve the problem but I could not manage to get it write even with that pattern.

Comment: This is how I was thinking when I set up the pattern marked with yellow in the xml above: The path should be the same as the GroupSearchBase, but with an additional cn because the cn is the name of the Role.   
  
This is what the textbook say about this property:  
"This property will be used when checking whether user has been assigned to a given role. Rather than searching the role in search base, by using this property direct search can be done."  
  
If anyone could shed more light on how to "think" about the RoleDNPattern, I would be happy :)